# iOS project has changed to OS X project

Tags: ios, xcode

The house of cards that is XCode has changed my project from iOS to OS X.

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the Schema because I've deleted that. In the build settings, the architecture settings are drawing from "OS X Default".

How do I change it back?

I fixed one of my projects by restarting the machine. One is still incorrectly configured though.

Many answers elsewhere suggest overriding the settings inherited from "OS X Default", which you can see in the following screen shot. Ideally the base settings should be "iOS Default".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and set your base SDK to iOS. Go to **Project (in upper left) -> Project (project name in submenu) -> Build Settings**. In Architectures menu select Base SDK as one of the iOS SDK.

Also, you said you deleted your Xcode schemes. That may also cause this. Try this:

1. On the left top corner of Xcode click on the scheme.
2. Click edit scheme.
3. In the new window change "Executable" from non to the name of your
   project scheme "target".

Comment: That will partially override the settings inherited from "OS X Default" but how do I change the root settings? I presume I need to edit the project file or else start again. Also my project doesn't have an executable: its a library.

Comment: Oh I take it back, that did fix it.